# How do I make multiple folders in a single location using relative path to the location?

Tags: linux, shell, mkdir

What I'm trying to do is create a number of folders in the "**~/Labs/lab4a/**" location (**~/Labs/lab4a/** already exists).

Say I want **folder1**, **folder2**, **folder3** all in the **lab4a** folder.

This isn't about making nested folders all at one go using the **mkdir -p** command or going in to **lab4a** and just making multiple folders at one go. I'm wondering is there a faster way using **mkdir** to create multiple folders in the same location using relative path.

*i.e*
prompt~/: **mkdir Labs/lab4a/folder1 folder2 folder3** To create all those folders in lab4a at once.

Comment: voting to close - this should be migrated to superuser, right?

Answer (score 60, accepted):

In Bash and other shells that support it, you can do

```
mkdir ~/Labs/lab4a/folder{1..3}
```

or

```
mkdir ~/Labs/lab4a/folder{1,2,3}
```

Other options:

```
mkdir $(seq -f "$HOME/Labs/lab4a/folder%03g" 3)

mkdir $(printf "$HOME/Labs/lab4a/folder%03g " {0..3})
```

Which will give you leading zeros which make sorting easier.

This will do the same thing in Bash 4:

```
mkdir ~/Labs/lab4a/folder{001..3}
```

Answer (score 45):

Use shell expansion :

```
mkdir Labs/lab4a/{folder1,myfolder,foofolder}
```

That such an underestimated possibility :)

my2c

Answer (score 2):

Go to console -

> cd ...
>
> mkdir {8...30}

Create multiple folders linux

Answer (score 2):

I would use `mkdir` with the `-p` option as it creates intermediate directories as required :

```
mkdir -p ~/var/www/html/site1/{site2/{html,logs,images},site{3..6},site7}
```

this creates this
[output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Vmhzo.png)
so in your case,

```
mkdir -p ~/Labs/lab4a/folder{1..3}
```